# How to Divide Navigational Bar using HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar in my webpage, but i was not able to divide it.  Some text to be on the left side and some text to be on the right side.  I tried using this code from this reference: *http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp*

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  When i add that code in

```
<ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
```

nothing happens.

Is their a better way of doing it?

Here is my list code

```
           <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">





      <li>
            <a href="#contact" >Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#services" >Join Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#about"  >About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#top" >Home</a>
        </li>


</section>
```

Comment: You don't have <ul> element in your code

Comment: are you looking something like this http://jsfiddle.net/eukL0koy/ ?

Comment: Include <ul> after div

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
ul li
{
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
}
ul li a
{
  padding:5px 10px;
    color:#666666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:18px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
}
ul li a:hover
{
   background:black;
   color:white;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/9xto6s0p/)

**OR**

```
.container
{
  background:gray;
  width:200px;
}
.container li
{
  padding:5px 10px;
    color:#666666;
   background:green;
  width:100%;


    font-size:18px;
  list-style-type:none;
}
.container li a
{
  text-decoration:none;


}
.container li a:hover
{
   background:red;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/3bb6rsxt/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in your case in [WorkingLink](http://jsfiddle.net/e0vs0hzf/)

You should first correct you markup then correct your css:

here i attach all correct form:

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Join Us</a></li>
      <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
     </ul>
   </ul>
  <div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 }

li {
 float: left;
 }

li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
 }

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
 }

.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 }
```